# UCMA 5.0 - File sharing doesn't work if conference is created by an UCMA application

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucma, lync-2013

I've developed an UCMA application that basically creates an ad-hoc conference and then adds some participants. The problem is that the file sharing (as well as screen sharing) doesn't work. I think this is due to the fact that UCMA doesn't support the app sharing, but in this case I don't want that my application can receive the files (or screen sharing call), but I just want this possibility to be available for all conference participants.

Any idea or suggestion?